# Como alterar o texto de "Read More" no HTML do blogger (blogspot)?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de alterar o texto de "Read More" que fica em cada post do blog para a mesma coisa, só que em português, já que todo o meu blog está em português, mas não consigo fazer a partir da guia Layout e no código só encontrei o seguinte sobre essa parte. Alguém sabe como alterar?

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
 <span expr:id='&quot;p&quot; + data:post.id'><data:post.body/></span>
  <script type='text/javascript'>var x=&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;,y=&quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;,z=&quot;<data:post.author/>&quot;,t=&quot;<data:post.timestamp/>&quot;;readmore(&quot;p<data:post.id/>&quot;)</script><b:else/><data:post.body/></b:if>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

se mudar essa parte: `/>&quot;;readmore(&quot` para "leia mais" no lugar do `readmore` acredito que resolva o seu problema. Ou no começo do seu código HTML alterar `en` para `pt-BR`